# Website redirecting inproperly

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http, laravel, webserver

I have the following issue, I'm building a website and it's deployed inside a subdirectory of my server, the website is a referral for sales services. Then on the homepage I have two links that references the two main categories of the products sold in it. Now the first link href's is /es/sports/ if I click on it I get a 404 error but if I copy paste the url in the browser then the page is shown correctly.

Note, when I click the link it is redirected to /sports/ instead of /es/sports/ as corresponds.

Maybe some htaccess configuration on the root of the public folder?

It's a laravel powered website.

The website url is the following. http://entrenamiento.com/es/ the links are the ones on the left sidebar.

[image]

Comment: Consider what it would be like to try to answer this question.  No source code, no examples, no demo.  How could we possibly know what is wrong here?

Comment: probably files are not in the same directory and you are not giving exact path use `..` to go to parent directory

Comment: The question has been enhanced @DanFarrell, now give it your best shot.

Comment: @Adamnick there are no files, just Laravel routes and a dynamic routing system I made.

Comment: You need to post your current htaccess rules, the current URL and the expected URL you want to use in the browser to start with.

Comment: Since the link target works when pasted into the browser, but in the dom inspector ( if you dont' use it, start right now! ) I can see my browser is not making a request to that url ( /es/deportes/ ), I can assume that the javascript is changing the script behavior.  It can't be .htaccess because direct URL works, .htaccess would have rewritten it.  It is probably a routing layer elsewhere.

Comment: @PanamaJack I have no access to the htaccess file. This website is a laravel application inside another laravel application, the client will not give me access to the parent application public folder in order to get the htaccess. The funny thing is that happens only with the sidebar links.

Comment: Thanks @DanFarrell for your comment, that's the same I'm thinking.

Answer (score 0):

First of all thanks for all comments and help. The thing is as follows, the parent website on the htaccess file has no support for trailing slashes after the URL. So once the trailing slash rule is enabled then the website works as expected. Thanks again